# www apontando para um ip e qualquer subdomínio para outro ip

Tags: dns

Eu tenho uma aplicação que trabalha com wildcard DNS. Então qualquer subdomínio é válido. Por exemplo:

teste.dominio.com.br
outro.dominio.com.br

Qualquer um dos links acima vão para um determinado IP.

Acontece que quero criar um site em wordpress para essa minha aplicação e ele irá funcionar na URL www.dominio.com.br

Atualmente minhas configurações de DNS estão assim:

Tipo A com nome @ apontando para IP X
Tipo A com nome * apontando para IP X

Então estou pensando em criar uma outra entrada DNS assim:

Tipo A com nome www apontando para o IP Y.

Em minha aplicação quando a pessoa entrar sem por nada, somente o dominio.com.br minha aplicação redireciona para o www.dominio.com.br

Eu gostaria de saber se essa é a melhor forma e se não vou fazer tudo parar de funcionar caso faça como pensei.

Answer (score 1):

Na zona DNS ficaria assim:

```
seudominio.ficticio     IN     A        1.2.3.4
*                       IN     A        2.2.3.4
www                     IN     CNAME    seudominio.ficticio
```

*Não estou considerando como está o SOA e outros parâmetros, mas esse é o escopo geral.

Pare redirecionar sem www. para www., é recomendável fazer fora da zona DNS porque dentro da zona DNS você pode apontar tudo para www., o que faria com que os emails ficassem assim @www.seudominio.ficticio.

Para o redirecionamento, aplique nos recursos do webserver (nginx, apache, iis, etc).

Exemplo, para Apache, o mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

Já fiz algo semelhante utilizando o **nginx**, você pode configurar como subdminios ou até mesmo em uma url unica, passando por parâmetros.

```
Exemplo:
   www.meusistema.com.br/cliente1 = 192.168.1.1
   www.meusistema.com.br/cliente2 = 192.168.1.5
```

Segue aqui a documentação http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html do nginx de como configurar vários servers com ips diferentes, ai você pode brincar com as regras ou pelo subdomínio como já disse.

Neste caso o seu **nginx** seria o seu IP Y, recebe todas as requisições e direciona para o servidor correto fazendo o serviço de proxy.

Encontrei este artigo com algo um pouco parecido [deploy-de-varias-aplicacoes-no-nginx-passenger-usando-subdomain-ou-suburi](http://1up4dev.org/2011/01/deploy-de-varias-aplicacoes-no-nginx-passenger-usando-subdomain-ou-suburi/).

Exemplo de arquivo que uso **nginx.conf**

```
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size  64;

    sendfile        on;
    tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  0;

    gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  teste.meudominio.com;
        location / {
        proxy_pass http://intancia1:8090/;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    }
    }

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  producao.meudominio.com;
        location / {
        proxy_pass http://instancia0:8080/;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    }

    #aqui vou adicionando quantos eu precisar e aponto para as maquinas que preciso

    }

}
```

Pode fazer o teste não vai se arrepender super simples de configurar.

Espero ter ajudado.